# Java Pdf Diff library

Tags: java, pdf, diff

Does anybody know of a open source Java library that will do robust diffing of the text parts of pdf files?

Ideally I would like something that would produce a diff in the form of a patch.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your expectations. There are many ways to create two different PDFs that appear exactly the same. Also keep in mind that PDFs do not have to have searchable text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the pdf text with http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/ and create a diff with http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch.

Answer (score 0):

If the PDFs are different only in text, you could also rasterize the pages and then look at the differences that way - we use that for regression testing output on our PDF code.

Comment: Are there any libraries or code for rasterizing a PDF file? Also on rasterize, will the result always be the same in terms of a MD5/SHA1 hash? Or will you have to diff it w/ a fuzzy comparison tool like Sikuli, etc.?

Comment: Just noticed that Apache PDFBox can rasterize PDF into images by pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of xdiffweb.com. It's a pure java opensource project based on apache pdfbox.

Comment: Thanks. The app appears to be down.